# Xcode : how to disable the tips "Document is not under source control" after upgrade the Xcode to 4.5 and upgrade osx to 10.7.5?

Tags: xcode, macos

After Upgrade Xcode from 4.3 to 4.5,osx from 10.7.4 to 10.7.5, and I come accross a very annoying issue that when I click every xcode project, an tip pop dialog will appear, and it prevent me from going on.
however, a lot project just for studying, so they are not be added to repository.

so how can I disable the dialog? 
thanks for your reply.

below is a  snapshot.

[image]

Comment: What did you do to make Xcode display "Loading Revision" in that status view?

Comment: I have no idea! maybe because of Upgrading mac osx to 10.7.5, or maybe upgrading xcode to 4.5!